# Rank Sqlite without looping

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

Coming from SQL Server, I could perform ranking in one query without looping which is faster and more clean using an expression like:

```
    WITH CTE AS ( SELECT ID,Position,  RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Category, order by Total desc ) AS rank FROM Products UPDATE CTE SET Position = rank
```

Then all the records would be ranked in a single query without looping. For SQLite, I feel like I have to loop over records ranking each which is likely to be low and take alot of RAM. 
Any Ideas to Rank SQLITe without looping?
Hint it's a C# WPF MVVM application

Comment: If you are going for an SQL based solution, why should anyone care it's for a c#, wpf MVVM application?

Comment: Because:
1.Stored procedures, or queries can be run in code
2.Someone can have a coded solution or library
3. It doesn't have to be a database solution 100%, and 
4. If 3 above, how can that fit in a MVVM pattern